# How at least approximately imitate col-md-1.5?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to adjust Bootstrap columns to look like this.

[image]

The thing is that on smaller devices I just want to hide this blank areas on the sides, thus I don't wanna use just margins or paddings.

How can I achieve that? col-md-1 seems too small for the indents, while col-md-2 is too broad.

[My Codepen](http://codepen.io/Alexnotonfire/pen/rxQVoz) with Bootstrap included.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  height: 230px;
  background-color: blue;
  max-width: 1050px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: use `col-md-offset-1`, then another `col-md-offset-1` inside your `col-md-9` - it's not exact as it's all relative but keeps your code cleaner than messing with CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to declare any new classes padding etc. You can simply nest the columns [bootply.com](http://www.bootply.com/3ku2frZuxg)

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just use a `@media` tag to cut the padding out when in mobile view? Makes it a lot easier. Just add the class below to either your container or row.

```
.marginClass{
  margin: 0 15px 0 15px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    .marginClass{
      margin: 0;
}
```

Actually you're probably better using margin. I've updated that.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what you're trying to achieve here. The container changes it width depending on the screen size using media queries. The white/blank space you're trying to get rid off is disappearing when the size of the screen is less than 768px.

What you can do, if I understand your question correct is [this option](http://codepen.io/robinsavemark/pen/mVQVrm):

HTML:

```
<!-- CONTAINER -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          This is column nested inside
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          This is column nested inside
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          This is column nested inside
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          This is column nested inside
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- CONTAINER FLUID -->
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          This is column nested inside
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          This is column nested inside
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          This is column nested inside
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          This is column nested inside
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container-fluid,
.container {
  height: 230px;
  background-color: #333;
/*   max-width: 1050px; */
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

html, body {
  color: #fff;
}
```